# How do I convert this program to work on a 64 bit machine for VB 6.3?

Tags: vba, 64-bit, 32-bit, autodesk

I have some VB 6.3 code that's normaly used on a 32 bit machine.
But I am now trying to run it on a 64bit machine and the code doesn't work.
It was programmed in VBA (autodesk)
Can someone help me with converting?

```
Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwProcessID As Long) As Long

Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
```

Comment: VBA 6.x is not VB 6.0, though there are commonalities.  However VBA is nothing outside the context of its host.  You might want to retag this.  Those are also some weird calls to be making in an AutoDesk macro.

Answer (score 0):

See [Compatibility Between the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx) for a list of affected API calls and examples of conditional compilation to call either the 32- or 64-bit Declare statement depending on the bitness.